# FME Find nearest polygon to a point

Tags: fme-form

The FME transformer "NeighborFinder" seems to have no problems finding the nearest point to a polygon. But I want it the other way around. I want to set the points as the "base" and the polygons as "candidates". But as a result I only get the same coordinates of the points.

How can I find the polygons nearest to the points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Matched features should be points, just as are the Base features - but with added attributes *_closest_candiate_x* and *_closest_candidate_y* which will be the point of the polygon closest to that point.